# Button not working after transitioning to "game over" scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a restart button after the player loses but am having trouble. As it stands, the player loses, an animation occurs to fade out of the game and fade in to the next scene where a canvas is presented. The canvas has a text box with the words "Game Over" in it and a button below it for restarting.

When pushing restart, nothing happens. Nothing happens to the color when hovering over or pressing the button. I think it has something to do with the fact that the scene has the scene changer object in order for the scene to fade in and out smoothly. I have tried fiddling with the raycast target box, among other things. Is there some sort of interference that happens with animations and buttons? Perhaps a layering issue? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some collider is overlapping the button?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Are you using an actual Button? It seems that you have said "raycast" on your button.

Solution 2: Make sure the UI is centered over top of your text box this way you properly select it!

Solution 3: Place a script on something that may be blocking the button if you are using "raycast" and do gameObject.SetActive(false);

These are all the methods I could think of! 
If you need any help, please feel free to add a comment.
Kind Regards ~~ SB